# count() without GROUP BY

Tags: sql

So I tried running this simple code

```sql
select COUNT(Ename),BOSS
from EMPLOYEE
WHERE BOSS=7839
```

but seems I did not get the output unless I use a "group by" boss below. I am not able to understand why can't I get output without "group by".

Can anybody explain in laymen terms. Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Because it's the standard SQL law. Even when there are outlaws like MySql who allow you to sin against the rules. Do you really want the sql engine to choose a random boss to go with that count?

Answer (score 3):

Count is an aggregate function. When you use Count (or any other aggregate function such as Count, Sum, Max, Min) next to select, then every other column item must be in group by. If you only use

```
select COUNT(Ename) -- there is no BOSS
from EMPLOYEE
```

then you don't have to use Group By. Lets say you have 5 columns: 1-COUNT(Ename), 2- BOSS, 3- column3, 4- column4, 5-column5. Then you would have to write select code as below:

```
select COUNT(Ename),BOSS, column3, column4, column5
from EMPLOYEE
WHERE BOSS=7839
GROUP BY
   BOSS, column3, column4, column5
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE boss=7839` should work.

`COUNT()`, like `AVG()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, is an *aggregate* function: it takes several rows, and outputs only one. So, since a row can have several columns, the value for one of those column is established by the function; the value chosen, among the many rows, for each of the other columns has to be specified somehow. This is normally done with `GROUP BY`.

If you ask `COUNT(*), name`, the request would not be fulfillable, because *which* employee's `name` would be returned across the rows? The first employee's? The last? A random one? -- and so an error is raised: *you cannot select the field unless you GROUP BY it*. Some RDBMS might allow skipping this specification, and use any of the previous options (MySQL uses the first row, I think) to resolve the ambiguity.

If you ask `COUNT(*), boss`, the request *is* fulfillable even if useless, because the WHERE condition specifies that `boss=7389`. So there is no ambiguity... this is actually the same as asking `SELECT COUNT(*), 7389 AS boss`. *But the RDBMS might not have the insight to understand this*, since it is an edge case (it is otherwise legal SQL, and it *could* happen, but it's not so common except in contrived cases); and might raise the same error as before on general principles.

Answer (score 0):

Either you specify `COUNT()` alone, or you ask for `COUNT(),boss` but latter implies `GROUP BY`.

COUNT() is an "aggregate function", which means that, unlike regular functions (that can be evaluated for each row), these ones wait for the dataset to complete before they can give you an answer. That's case for SUM(), MIN(), MAX() or such as long it regards a whole column.

This means that you cannot ask for their value while the dataset is being parsed and, for this reason, cannot display their result aside the current value of a field (here being "boss"), because it just makes no sense. They're meant to be displayed as a bottom line after the data themselves.

However, you may do some groupings, according to a given criteria, that will sort your table along, then forming some subgroups each having a same value for the fields you specified in GROUP BY. These groups will each act as a mini-table upon which you aggregate functions can be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

When we use an aggregate function it return a single value. Using multiple aggregate function in a single query is also ok but when we mix up aggregate and normal then this become a mismatch. If we want to mix them up then we need to make others column on group by

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a situation that may also need a similar SQL to yours, i.e. get the first row of some condition, meanwhile retrieve the total count of same condition, and don't want to execute two SQLs due to network latency. Here is what I finally got:

```sql
WITH tmp_table as (
    SELECT foo, bar
    FROM some_table
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY ...
)
SELECT foo, bar, (SELECT count(*) FROM tmp_table) as cnt
FROM tmp_table 
LIMIT 1
```

In SQL above, clickhouse can get the result with only one table scan.

It gives exactly same execution plan with and without the `count` part,

This strangely written SQL should not bring extra computation cost.

---

EDIT: also tested in MySQL and SQLite

Comment: The OP did not indicate what DBMS he is using so I'm not sure whether a solution for [clickhouse](https://clickhouse.com/) will be suitable.

Comment: @Abra Sorry, I implied that because I reached this question frrom Googleing clickhouse blah blah..

Answer (score -1):

You need `GROUP BY` because `COUNT()` is an aggregate function. Really, the best way to do this is by using the `HAVING` command:

```
SELECT COUNT(ename), boss
FROM employee
GROUP BY boss
HAVING boss = 7839
```

Comment: uhm, no. HAVING is there for the aggregation functions. A criteria on a field should be in the WHERE clause.